# Django/Postgres integration issues

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Whenever I try to integrate the postgres database into my django application to deploy on heroku, it continues to display this error despite the correct integration made on the `settings.py`.

How do I fix this?

```
File "/home/tochikaze/Projects/b-aid/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type timestamp with time zone to interval
LINE 1: ...LUMN "last_login" TYPE interval USING "last_login"::interval
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a timestamp with timezone to an interval:

```
select '2021-07-13 7:22'::timestamptz::interval;
ERROR:  cannot cast type timestamp with time zone to interval
LINE 1: select '2021-07-13 7:22'::timestamptz::interval;
```

So doing this:

```
"last_login" TYPE interval USING "last_login"::interval
```

is not going to work.